# UDP server not reachable from outside home

Tags: networking, server, udp, port

I have made a small UDP server according to [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/SimpleUdpServer.htm).

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class SimpleUdpSrvr
{
public static void Main()
{
  int recv;
  byte[] data = new byte[1024];
  IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);

  Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                  SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

  newsock.Bind(ipep);
  Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");

  IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
  EndPoint Remote = (EndPoint)(sender);

  recv = newsock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);

  Console.WriteLine("Message received from {0}:", Remote.ToString());
  Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));

  string welcome = "Welcome to my test server";
  data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
  newsock.SendTo(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, Remote);
  while(true)
  {
     data = new byte[1024];
     recv = newsock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
   
     Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));
     newsock.SendTo(data, recv, SocketFlags.None, Remote);
  }
  }
  }
```

- When I try to access it from my local network it works fine.
- I then added an exception to my firewall to allow port 9050 through the firewall.
- I also forwarded port 9050 through my Netgear router.
- However, I cannot reach the UDP server from outside and when I start the UDP server and check for the port via [this port checker website](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/), the port always shows up as closed.
- I have two other ports open for rather old online games and for them the port forwarding works well.
- Also tried to change the port to different port numbers but no success.

Any help on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out the steps were right.
The messages actually came through to the server, only the port checker website above still shows the connection as closed.